# kohana orm top user

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I have 2 tables

The users and comments

The comments have a many to one relationship with the users

Trying to think of a way using ORM to get top users based on amount of comments

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT users.username, COUNT(comments.id) AS total 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN comments 
ON users.id = comments.user_id 
GROUP BY users.username 
ORDER BY COUNT(comments.id) DESC
```

Translated to ORM:

```
ORM::factory('user')
   ->select('user.username', array('COUNT("comments.id")', 'total'))
   ->join('comments', 'INNER')
   ->on('user.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
   ->group_by('user.username')
   ->order_by('total', 'DESC')
   ->find_all();
```

Comment: Just checking, isn't this only returning users that have comments? E.g. if a user has zero comments it won't be part of the record set?